# Passing 2D char to function and only first element is filled

Tags: c

I am passing a 2D char array to a function.  If I print it in the calling function, I see it is filled with some elements.  If I print it in the called function, only the first element is filled:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compareTopString(char * string1, char * string2){
    printf("%s %s\n", string1, string2);
    return 5;
}

int getMaxTopics(int numP, int numTop, int * subject[][1000]){

    for(int k = 0;k < numP;k++){
        printf("%s\n", subject[k]);
    }


    return 0;
}

int main() {


    int numP;
    int numTop;
    char subject[1000][1000];
    scanf("%d", &numP);
    scanf("%d", &numTop);

    for (int i = 0; i < numP; i++){
        scanf("%s", subject[i]);
    }

    printf("%d", getMaxTopics(numP, numTop, &subject));

    for(int k = 0;k < numP;k++){
        printf("%s\n", subject[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change to `int getMaxTopics(int numP, int numTop, char subject[][1000]){` and `getMaxTopics(numP, numTop, subject)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I want to pass a pointer to a char 2d array, so that it is not passed by value (ie no copying a big 2d array).  How would I do that?

Comment: It is treated as a pointer. The contents of the array is not be copied.

Comment: `char subject[][1000]` and `char (*subject)[1000]` are the same in parameters of function. `subject` is pointer to `char [1000]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `char` and `int`. Are you sure that compiled without warnings?